# google cloud hates my import - ssh and ping not working, http:// and web ssh is.. why?

Tags: ssh, virtualization, google-cloud-platform, import

I have imported a VM (160gb CentOS7 guest, Hyper-V Host) the new google cloud vm has a GEC ip of `x.x.x.203`. I can connect to the source machine `g.g.g.209`via ssh port 22 and it responds to pings, (i.e. firewalls on the CentOS source are configured fine). However I can connect to the new instance in the google cloud only via web console (or port 80 i.e. `http://x.x.x.203` resolves correctly). Other than that `x.x.x.203` has No ping. No port 22 response at all. No gcloud compute response on my desktop machine. ssh or `gcloud compute` only work via the web panels, and then they DO work. So logins are working on `x.x.x.203`.

I have altered the firewalls on google cloud but they seem to be blocking this inbound requests (NB: ping and ssh 22 are both unresponsive from the wider net) do I need to set up some sort of routing? My other non imported servers all work via ssh fine under the same `default rules` here are my rules. Like I say they work for the other 3 servers not for the import.

```
allow-fivefiveeight                      default                       INGRESS    1000      tcp:558
ce-replicator-rule                       default                       INGRESS    1000      tcp:1500
cloudendure-network-1136892c-allow-http  cloudendure-network-1136892c  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80
default-allow-http                       default                       INGRESS    1000      tcp:80
default-allow-https                      default                       INGRESS    1000      tcp:443
default-allow-icmp                       default                       INGRESS    65534     icmp
default-allow-internal                   default                       INGRESS    65534     tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp
default-allow-rdp                        default                       INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389
default-allow-ssh                        default                       INGRESS    65534     tcp:22
sg-for-instance-i-44444477777-1136892c   cloudendure-network-1136892c  INGRESS    1000      tcp:443,tcp:80,tcp:22,tcp:3389
```

I have googled this to death for 24 hours. Please help?

Why is "external" access to this server unavailable? While available on the source machine?

Answer (score 2):

Iptables on CentOS could be enabled by default, which could block external traffic to the VM instance. You could verify by following the instruction on this GCP [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#centosiptables), and as a workaround you could disable iptables.